# update table if exist

Tags: php, database

In my table I check values is there or not if it's there I need to increase `qty` but it's not working. What mistake I done?

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "psw";
$dbname = "database";

$myemail ='my@gmail.com';
$image = '1';
$user = 'user';
$device = '1';
$product = '2';
$qty = '100';
$status = '1';
$orderno = '2';

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablemname(email,image_url,user_id,device_id,product_id,qty,status,order_no) VALUES ('$myemail','$image','$user','$device','$product','$qty','$status','$orderno') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qty=1";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Post your error message too!!

Comment: @Saty No error msg evertime it's inserted

Comment: What is your duplicate key? You could print je values before inserting to see if the values are really the same.

Comment: Check my updated question i added my table structure

Comment: I cant really tell from that picture if you have an unqiue index on qty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to add +1 to qty :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablemname(email,image_url,user_id,device_id,product_id,qty,status,order_no)
VALUES ('$myemail','$image','$user','$device','$product','$qty','$status','$orderno') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qty= qty+1";
```

A warning, this work only on a value that should be unique. So when i see your table, I am not sure it will work...

Comment: What is the problem in my table it add one more row not update

Comment: I can't see your unique index, so i can't be sure it will do  what you want. But if it's working, then ignore my warning ;)

Comment: I am not understand what i need to be done can please tell me